# Remove automatic paragraph from wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress

I've just done with my first wordpress theme. My problem is, when I create a new text-widget, the output gets automatically added in paragraph and I also see `<br />` tag inserted after every line. Can anybody help me here!

I've added `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` to my functions.php but it doesn't worked.

Comment: All you need is to add `remove_filter('widget_text_content', 'wpautop');` in your functions.php

Answer (score 21):

Maybe this can help you (or others too):

```
// remove <br> tags from text widget content, from 4.8 version WP adds these tags
remove_filter('widget_text_content', 'wpautop');
```

Answer (score 5):

As of WordPress 4.8  the "Automatically Add Paragraphs" checkbox on the text widgets has been removed.

However there is a plugin I wrote in the repository to add the checkbox back in.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-paragraphs-option-to-text-widget/

Comment: Does auto add or auto-not-add paragraphs as of 4.8? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1:**

Go to widget page, edit your text widget and uncheck checkbox under textarea.
[image: how to remove paragraphs from text widget content]

**Option #2:**

Create your own hook, it will have influence on all text widgets:

```
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'wpse8170_widget_display_callback', 10, 3 );
function wpse8170_widget_display_callback( $instance, $widget, $args ) {
    $instance['filter'] = false;
    return $instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress has an "Automatically Add Paragraphs" checkbox on the text widgets which allow you to turn off the paragraphs.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Add below code in functions.php

// Remove automatic paragraph from wordpress widget

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

Comment: Careful: this one removes it from the entire content, not the widget.